# No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.test.OutputDestination' available

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, junit5, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-contract

I am trying to use spring cloud contracts for messaging.
I have a producer and a consumer who is publishing and consuming from `rabbitmq`.
they are working fine when I run both these spring boot applications.

however, when I try to `mvn clean install` , generated `ContractVerifierTest` fails with the error

```
2022-01-18 14:35:55.982 ERROR 62575 --- [           main] s.StreamOutputDestinationMessageReceiver : Exception occurred while trying to read a message from  a channel with name [fraud]

org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.test.OutputDestination' available
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:351) ~[spring-beans-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:342) ~[spring-beans-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1172) ~[spring-context-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.cloud.contract.verifier.messaging.stream.StreamOutputDestinationMessageReceiver.receive(StreamOutputDestinationMessageReceiver.java:43) ~[spring-cloud-contract-verifier-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at org.springframework.cloud.contract.verifier.messaging.stream.StreamOutputDestinationMessageReceiver.receive(StreamOutputDestinationMessageReceiver.java:55) ~[spring-cloud-contract-verifier-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at org.springframework.cloud.contract.verifier.messaging.stream.StreamOutputDestinationMessageReceiver.receive(StreamOutputDestinationMessageReceiver.java:30) ~[spring-cloud-contract-verifier-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at org.springframework.cloud.contract.verifier.messaging.stream.StreamStubMessages.receive(StreamStubMessages.java:59) ~[spring-cloud-contract-verifier-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at org.springframework.cloud.contract.verifier.messaging.stream.StreamStubMessages.receive(StreamStubMessages.java:31) ~[spring-cloud-contract-verifier-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at org.springframework.cloud.contract.verifier.messaging.internal.ContractVerifierMessaging.receive(ContractVerifierMessaging.java:65) ~[spring-cloud-contract-verifier-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
```

I have `spring-cloud-stream`, `spring-cloud-stream-binder-rabbit`, `spring-cloud-starter-contract-verifier`, `spring-cloud-stream:test-binder` dependencies in my `pom` as well.

My spring boot application class is configured like this

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableBinding(Source.class)
public class ProducerApplication {
```

It is sending the message to the destination topic from tests as well. However, it fails to read it

```
@Test
    public void validate_contract_name() throws Exception {
        // when:
            trigger(); // this happens fine

        // then:
            ContractVerifierMessage response = contractVerifierMessaging.receive("destination-name",
                    contract(this, "contract_name.yml")); // THIS FAILS
            assertThat(response).isNotNull();
```

I have annotated my base test class with these

```
@SpringBootTest(classes = ProducerApplication.class, webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.NONE)
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@AutoConfigureMessageVerifier
```

I have verified that `OutputDestination` class is available in the classpath.

I have `org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-stream:test-jar:test-binder:3.2.1:test` in the classpath.

`spring-boot-starter-parent` version is `2.6.2`. spring cloud version is `2021.0.0`

I have configured `spring-cloud-contract-maven-plugin` version `3.1.0` to use `JUNIT5`

Comment: Your configuration is inconclusive. However, what I am able to extract from it is that there is nothing related to spring-cloud-stream in it, You are not bootstrapping a test binder anywhere, so Input/Output destinations are not created. I am not an expert on s-c-contract, but working with Marcin daily I know there are hundreds of tests in s-c-contract that using Input/Output destination, so consider looking at them for guadance,

Comment: Thanks for the response @OlegZhurakousky. I have added more details about the configuration. Actually I have 2 contracts in this project. one for HTTP and one for Messaging. HTTP test works fine. Messaging test doesn't work

Comment: the issue was that I didn't have `@ImportAutoConfiguration(TestChannelBinderConfiguration.class)` in my base test. thanks

Comment: or remove following dependency: spring-cloud-stream-test-support.

Comment: @RobinHo thanks for your great answer which helped me after one day to solve that problem, but could you explain why removing this dependency solved the problem?